# How to conditional format the dataframe

Tags: python, css, pandas

I have a dataframe with certain no of columns and rows.I want conditional format on 3 color scale  based on values like on excel.There is no special condition for values

[image]

I have created a html table and set style.But it does not render like expected.

```
 cm = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("3_colors", ["mediumseagreen", "khaki", "salmon"])

styles = [ dict(selector="th", props=[("background-color", "#FFBC00")]),
           dict(selector ='tr', props=[("background-color", cm), ('font-weight', 'bold')] )

html1 = df.style.set_table_styles(styles).background_gradient(cmap = cm).render()
```

Is it even possible what i am trying to achieve.Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
thresholds = [50,75]
def colorize(a,thresholds=thresholds):
    if a < thresholds[0]: 
        return 'background-color: green'
    elif a<thresholds[1]:
        return 'background-color: orange'
    else:
        return 'background-color: red'


df.style.applymap(colorize, thresholds=thresholds)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Utilize custom styler functions! They give you broad control over dataframe styling:

### Make a random dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records((np.random.random((5,5))*10).round(2))
```

### Define a styler function:

```
def styler(x):
    if x < 3:
        return 'background: red'
    elif x < 6:
        return 'background: green'
    else:
        return 'background: blue'
```

### Apply the styler functions:

```
df.style.applymap(styler)
```

The result:
[A styled DataFrame, conditionally formatted by cell value!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDjD7.png)